# Vertically center list item content with Flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

I have the following simple list...

```css
ul{background:wheat;height:200px;text-align:center;}
li{height:200px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;background:green;color:white;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

I am trying to get the item contents to be vertically centered, is flexbox the way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes flexbox is great for this. You can use the existing layout and just use `inline-flex` on the `li` and set `align-items: center` to vertically center the content.

```css
ul{background:wheat;height:200px;text-align:center;}
li{height:200px;display:inline-flex;margin-right:10px;background:green;color:white;align-items:center;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

You could also just set the `line-height` of the content to the height of the parent and it will center the content vertically.

```css
ul{background:wheat;height:200px;text-align:center;}
li{height:200px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;background:green;color:white;line-height:200px;}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could add padding on the top of your li

```css
ul{background:wheat;height:200px;text-align:center;}
li{height:200px;padding-top: 100px;display:inline-block;margin-right:10px;background:green;color:white;}
```

```html
since you directly defined the height of the box I was able to just divide that value in half in order to center the content using padding. If you don't know the difference between padding margin and border. Look into the box model in css. It is one of the most fundamental concepts you will need to grasp to have a good understanding of css.

<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
</ul>
```